# i18next is throwing an error props.t is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am passing  title to my Layout Component like this

```
 <Route
      exact
        path="/services/edit"
        render={(props) => {
          return (
            <MainLayout title={props.t("SERVICES")}  >
              <ServicesEdit {...props} />
            </MainLayout>
          );
        }}
      />
```

but the react throws an error

```
props.t is not a function
```

Cant find the error. The component is exported like this . What is the problem?

```
export default withTranslation()(Router)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `props` argument to `render function` of Route is basically the `route props` and not the component props. Since you have used HOC around the component, translation  function `t` will be available from component props

You can update the code as follows and it should work

```
const Router = (props) => {
    /* Other logic */
    return <Route
        exact
        path="/services/edit"
        render={(routeProps) => {
          return (
            <MainLayout title={props.t("SERVICES")}  >
              <ServicesEdit {...routeProps} />
            </MainLayout>
          );
        }}
      />
}

export default withTranslation()(Router);
```